# htaccess internal rewrite across domains?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to point a subfolder from one domain to another on my vhost (mediatemple). I want to use internal rewrites, not 301 redirects. Here's the goal

```
http://www.clientdomain.com/blog/$1 --> http://www.mydomain.com/wpmu/clientdomain/$1
```

On the server side, the structure looks like this:

```
/x/y/z/domains/clientdomain.com/html/blog/ -- htaccess file is here
/x/y/z/domains/mydomain.com/html/wpmu/ -- wpmu installation
```

So far I've only had success with 301 redirects, but my goal is to mask things such that wpmu can power the client's blog without revealing its location. Here's my working 301 redirect:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/wpmu/clientdomain/$1 [NC]
```

Is there an easy way to convert it to an internal rewrite? I haven't seen anything but 301 redirects for this type of thing...

Thanks in advance,

Casey

Comment: Did you try the absolute filesystem path instead of the URI?

Comment: I haven't had success with that yet; are filesystem paths specified differently from URIs in htaccess? When I use %{PATH_INFO} in my RewriteCond the match fails.

Comment: Filesystem paths did not work because the mod_rewrite won't drop below ${DOCUMENTROOT}

Comment: This definitely seems to be the case for rules specified in `.htaccess` because `mod_rewrite` sends the request to the Apache internal redirect handler, which apparently parses it as a URL (I have trouble locating exactly where this happens). In a server context though (`httpd.conf`), the source code suggests that an absolute (accessible) filepath should also work. (This is purely supplemental information for the curious; for your specific problem I think your solution is the only way for this to work via `.htaccess` alone barring existing Alias directives)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, the only way to achieve this rewrite across vhosted domains is to use a symbolic link between domains to fool mod_rewrite into thinking it's doing an internal rewrite

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing *is* an internal rewrite.

For a 301 redirect you would have to write [L,R=301]:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/blog/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/wpmu/clientdomain/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: `www.mydomain.com` isn't the domain under which the `RewriteRule` is being performed, so the rule he has will perform an external redirection as he specified.

Comment: Ah, ok, now I get it. Then the only way without revealing the true URI is to act as a proxy.
See mod_proxy for example: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_proxy.html

Or use symlinks on the filesystem

ln -s /x/y/z/domains/clientdomain.com/html/blog/ /x/y/z/domains/mydomain.com/html/wpmu/ should help

Comment: I wound up using symlinks, rewriting across domains does not work.